# I need to create a function in R that takes a matrix as its input and returns a list

Tags: r

This is the code i tried to use to solve the problem but my results are not accurate. Any suggestions will be appreciated. thanks

```
> fun1 <- function(x,y){
   ##input of the function
   x<- matrix(data = x, nrow=20,ncol =0 )
  ##get mean of rows and columns
   mean_row<- rowMeans(x)
   mean_col<- colMeans(x)
   ##create the return value y as a list
   y<- list(x, mean_row, mean_col)
   return(y)
 }
```

Comment: `ncol  = 0` should that be `ncol = 1`

Comment: Only use both `nrow` and `ncol` if you are sure of the size of the vector `x`. Otherwise use just one of them. Also, it's `fun1 <- function(x)`, there is no need for a second argument `y`.

Comment: also if ncol(x) <= 1, rowMeans(x) = x :)